# Print two arrays side by side

Tags: c#, arrays

```
public static void CategoryX(string categories)
{
    string[] codes = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
    string[] names = { "FIRST LETTER", "SECOND LETTER", "THIRD LETTER", "FOURTH LETTER", "FIFTH LETTER" };
}
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
A FIRST LETTER
B SECOND LETTER
C THIRD LETTER
D FOURTH LETTER
E FIFTH LETTER
```

I have tried using a for statement using GroupBy which hasn't worked and also tried comparing the two arrays using a bool statement AND made a third array which contains codes and names as elements.

Comment: Not sure whats your logic is. But this is a clear case for key value pair in c#.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0#code-try-1?view=net-7.0

Comment: Start using classes instead of arrays that depend on each other via index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop:

```
string[] result = new string[codes.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < codes.Length; i++)
{
   result[i] = codes[i] + " " + names[i];
   Console.WriteLine(result[i]);
}
```

This assumes that both arrays have the same length. If you can't assure this, you should check which array is the shortest, e.g. by `Math.Min(codes.Length, names.Length)`. If you don't want to process the data at a further pont, you don't have to use the result array.

As an alternative, you might also look at LINQ's [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-zip-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-1)))) method:

```
foreach(var entry in codes.Zip(names))
{
   Console.WriteLine(entry.Item1 + " " + entry.Item2);
}
```

If you only want to print the values, via [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0#system-string-join(system-string-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-string)))), this can be even reduced to a one-liner:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n",codes.Zip(names, (c,n) => c + " " + n)));
```

Comment: Thank you this has been super helpful, I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

Linq approach

```
codes.Zip(names, (x, y) => x + " " + y).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```